# Synchronous and Asynchronous messages in Collaboration Diagram

Tags: uml, collaboration

In the Collaboration diagram, we represent a message with a solid-headed line :

[image]

Moreover, in a sequence diagram, we can show a synchronous message with a solid-headed line and an asynchronous message with an open arrowhead:

[image]

Is there a way to indicate a synchronous and asynchronous message in the collaboration diagram, or UML didn't specify that in the collaboration diagram, so we are not interested in showing such information in this diagram and we just use a solid-headed line ?

Answer (score 1):

The [UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) specifies that the arrows in a sequence diagram and the arrows in a collaboration diagram (or as it nowadays is called, a communication diagram) conveys the same information.

This means that where you use a open arrowhead or a dashed line in a sequence diagram, you can use the same arrow style in a communication diagram with the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks. So this means that I can still use an open arrow head for asynchronous messages and a closed arrowhead for synchronous messages in the collaboration diagram?  If yes, does this will conflict with Procedural and flat sequence respresentation that uses open/closed arrowheads like in here:  https://praveenthomasln.wordpress.com/tag/interactions-in-uml/    ?

Comment: Yes, you can use an open arrow head for asynchronous messages and a closed arrow head for synchronous ones. I believe the difference between a procedural and a flat sequence is more in the structure of the sequence numbers (nested numbers or only top level) than in the type of arrow used.